# SQL query - select uncommon values from 2 tables

Tags: sql, duplicates

Today I was asked following question in my interview for a QA and because of incorrect query, I did not get selected. From then on, my mind is itching to get the correct answer for the following scenario:

I was given following 2 tables:

```
Tabel A  |       |Table B
---------        ----------
**ID**          **ID**          
--------        -----------
0  |            | 5 |
1  |            | 6 |
2  |            | 7 |
3  |            | 8 |
4  |            | 9 |
5  |            | 10|
6  |            -----
----
```

And following output was expected using an SQL query:

```
**ID**
--------
| 0  |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 7  |
| 8  |
| 9  |
| 10 |
--------
```

Thanks everyone, I really like this forum and from now on will be active here to learn more and more about SQL. I would like to make it my strong point rather a weak so as not to get kicked out of other interviews.  I know there is a long way to go.  However beside all of your responses, I came to draft the following query and would like to know from the experts here of their opinion about my query (and the reason why they think of what they think):

BTW the query has worked on MSSQLSRV-2008 (using Union or Union All, didn't matter to the result I got):

select ID from A where ID not in (5,6)

union

select ID from B where ID not in (5,6)

Is this really an efficient query?

Comment: A simple SQL query no type of DB mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

If you want values in only one of two tables, I would use a `full outer join` and condition:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id)
from tableA a full outer join
     tableB b
     on a.id = b.id
where a.id is null or b.id is null;
```

Of course, if the job at a company that uses MS Access or MySQL, then this isn't the right answer, because these systems don't support `full outer join`.  You can also do this in more complicated ways using `union all` and aggregation or even with other methods.

EDIT:

Here is another method:

```
select id
from (select a.id, 1 as isa, 0 as isb from tablea union all
      select b.id, 0, 1 from tableb
     ) ab
group by id
having sum(isa) = 0 or sum(isb) = 0;
```

And another:

```
select id
from tablea
where a.id not in (select id from tableb)
union all
select id
from tableb
where b.id not in (select id from tablea);
```

As I think about this, it is a pretty good interview question (even though I've just given three reasonable answers).

Comment: wierd.. sql server gives me values which are not common if i remove and run without coalesce, given that `where a.id is null or b.id is null` condition is present

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** See Gordon answer above for a better request, this is very inneficient way of doing what you want.

I think this should do the trick :

```
(SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT id IN (SELECT A.id FROM A, B WHERE A.id = B.id))
UNION
(SELECT * FROM B WHERE NOT id IN (SELECT A.id FROM A, B WHERE A.id = B.id))
```

You could avoid the duplication of `SELECT A.id ...`by using a temporary table.

Comment: . . I would use `union all` to avoid the unnecessary step of removing duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agree with you about the unecessary `WHERE A.id = B.id` which can be simply replaced by your query, but I don't see what will be the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` in this case since there will be no duplicate values between the `SELECT` ?

Comment: . . `union` goes through the effort of removing duplicates, even if there aren't any (in every database I know of).  `union all` performs better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay, it's a matter of performance, I though you were talking about a difference in output. I won't update my request because it would be the same as yours, so I made an edit to head to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

without full outer joins...

```
Select id
from (Select id from tableA
      Union all
      Select id from tableB) Z
group by id
Having count(*) = 1
```

or using [Except and Intersect](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) .....

```
(Select id from tableA Except Select id from tableB)
Union
(Select id from tableB Except Select id from tableA)
```

or ....

```
(Select id from tableA union Select id from tableB)
Except
(Select id from tableA intersect Select id from tableB)
```

Comment: second query does not work in MSSQLSERVER2008. Just tried it.

Comment: it should,  `Except` and `Intersect` were introduced in SQL Server 2008.  I have SQL 2012 and it works there, so syntax is correct.